# How to update the date month by one in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have a default date with something like `<statdate> 30/7/2015 <statedate>` in my data.xml file. What I want to do is I want to increase the month by one month each. I have sucessfully link my java class to xml by using this code below. I have the method code below

link to xml

//read the xml

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File data = new File("data.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(data);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        //get the initialized date
        Date date_int = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date);
        cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.setTime(date_int);
        cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    }
}
```

Method

```
private static void updateMonth(Calendar cal2) {
            cal2.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just simple do like below:

```
public static void updateMonth(Calendar cal2) {
    cal2.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
}
```

After you call the updateMonth method, you can get the new month from the calendar. For example:

```
    ...
  cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  ...
```

Comment: Hi Kenny, thank you for your reply. I am wondering do I need to call the node to update my month? Such as something this in my updateMonth method?
NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();   
    Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);

Comment: I think you can do so. Just put the node as a parameter to the method and set the value of the node to your new date value. :)

Answer (score 0):

[`Calendar.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add-int-int-) can be used to add (or subtract) an arbitrary unit of time:

```
private static void updateMonth(Calendar cal) {
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
}
```

It also has the benefit of correctly rolling over other fields if needed.  For example, if your date was `Tue Dec 01 00:00:00 EST 2015`, adding one month using `add` will yield `Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 2016`.

Comment: Hi Equality, thank you for your reply. So this add method will automatically add each month from the xml file by one whenever the program start right?

Comment: @Anonymous: Not _automatically_.  You need to call this method with the calendar you want to adjust (`cal2` in your code).  Then you can do whatever you want with `cal2` (e.g. use it to update the same node in the DOM from which it was derived).

Comment: @Anonymous: You'll need to update your question with a [mcve] of what you're trying to do beyond what you originally asked (or open a separate question).